# How can I make firestore REST API PATCH request?

Tags: firebase, rest, http, google-cloud-firestore

I set my Firestore simple database with one field, and I checked the the `GET` request according to docs:

```
/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/cities/LA
```

But I am unable to understand patch request docs. In this patch request pattern:
[https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project_id}/databases/{database_id}/documents/{document_path}?updateMask.fieldPaths=KEYVALUE.VALUE](https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/%7Bproject_id%7D/databases/%7Bdatabase_id%7D/documents/%7Bdocument_path%7D?updateMask.fieldPaths=KEYVALUE.VALUE)

I am confuse, how shall I use this to make a patch request?. How can I obtain the document path?
kindly guide.
thanks

Comment: Have you check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/patch)? or are you asking how to make a PATCH request.? The URL remains same, you just change the request from GET to PATCH with updated data.

Comment: the url is different, its demanding document path and obviously the JSON data along with request body will be sent

Comment: I want to see how others are using so I can make one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass updated data in the format specified in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents):

```js
fetch("https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/databases/(default)/documents/[COLLECTION]/[DOC_NAME]?currentDocument.exists=true&updateMask.fieldPaths=name&alt=json", {
  headers: {
    authorization: "Bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]",
    "content-type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ fields: { name : { stringValue : "Username"}}}),
  method: "PATCH"
});
```

Do note the complete request URL. It contain a query parameter `updateMask.fieldPaths=name`. If that's missing the the complete document will be replaced by new data. The `fields` property is a map and you must specify the field type as shown above. You can find more about Value types [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/Value)

Comment: Thanks alot. This work fine  when I make patch request using insomnia, but when I write in Javascript . This gives error 401(ACCESS DENIED )

Comment: @angrybird are you using the same token both in Insomnia and JS ?

Comment: I figured out, it was CORS policy which did not allow http request. I tried live server from VS code and it works perfectly. Thankyu so much for your guidance.

Comment: yes I did. But I need another help. I have to run script on HMI (Easy pro builder) and it uses requests.js to make http requests , can you guide me how can I make this PATCH request using requests.js? Thanks

Comment: @angrybird I just saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69153733/how-to-use-firestore-in-hmi-script). I'm not sure if you know that. But since it's a separate question I'd recommend following the question or ask your own with some more details :)